Outdated packages in apt
It seems that many packages cannot be updated to reasonably recent versions, for instance nodejs' most recent version available is v12. That is causing problems with other projects that require more recent versions. This is not limited to just nodejs but I see it happening all over the place. For reference nodejs's latest version in apt is deemed as ancient in:
https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/7365#issuecomment-1970295188
How should we deal with this?
Edit: OK, I just found out there is something called nix. I just used it (took 10 minutes) and managed to get what I needed and I see people recommending it too: https://nixos.org/
Edit: Given that people keep telling me that this is "related" to some other question:
This is not that related, this post is about aptitude using ancient versions of software, so old that they start making dependencies unusable and getting in the way of the user's workflow and productivity. The latest version of nodejs seems to be v22.8. I probably can work fine with v18, but I have access at most to v12. So this is not really about asking for the latest version

Related: Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?

@steeldriver This is not that related, this post is about aptitude using ancient versions of software, so old that they start making dependencies unusable and getting in the way of the user's workflow and productivity. The latest version of nodejs seems to be v22.8. I probably can work fine with v18, but I have access at most to v12. So this is not really about asking for the latest version.

If you solved your problem, consider putting it in a self-answer instead of in an edit!

@Anerdw This is not a solution, I just moved away from aptitude. Aptitude still has problems, BIG problems.

apt and the package tools use Ubuntu repositories by default; and the stable release model that Debian & Ubuntu both use means that only security fixes are backported to existing versions; not newer packages...   on top of that is the lack of contributors willing to spend time doing the required SRU (stable release updates) etc. & extra workload of updating packages that are released as stable.

@guiverc please read my answer above. I am going to copy paste it here:
This is not that related, this post is about aptitude using ancient versions of software, so old that they start making dependencies unusable and getting in the way of the user's workflow and productivity. The latest version of nodejs seems to be v22.8. I probably can work fine with v18, but I have access at most to v12. So this is not really about asking for the latest version
And, just in case, I am going to copy paste it a second time as part of the original question.

aptitude uses the apt software sources and doesn't have its own... I don't see how the duplicate link doesn't apply.. as if I do a (CLI or https://packages.ubuntu.com/) query on packages that are available; then use apt or aptitude to install they'll both install the same version as both use the same software lists

Nodejs v12 suggests you are using Ubuntu 22.04. If you want newer software, try a newer release of Ubuntu. v18 is in Ubuntu 24.04. v20 will be in Ubuntu 24.10. Packaging node is difficult (see https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/nodejs), which it why it takes volunteer packagers a long time to get it right in Debian and Ubuntu. Note that node's recommended deployment method is a Docker container, not apt.

This question is similar to: Unable to install nodejs script from nodesource. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@guiverc@user535733 The thing is simple, If I do sudo apt install x and the most recent version is unusable, then there is a problem with apt. This is a SEVERE issue, that is the reality, regardless of how you see it. But as a user, my job goes as far as to let you know about the problem, what you do with it is your business. I will move on and use a tool that allows me to do my job.

That last comment is exactly what the duplicate link tries to explain.. Ubuntu, like Debian upstream, is a stable release system with security fixes backported to the version that was packaged at release time (except in very rare circumstances)..  To use later packages you move to a newer release, or use alternate package formats (ie. not deb based which are deemed stable prior to release & thus have only security fixes applied via SRU). apt is working as intended per Debian's stable release intention.
